# Reflectors and reflections in category theory

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to understand the terminology for reflective subcategories.

On nLab we find the statement that the left adjoint is ["called the reflector, and a functor which is a reflector is called a reflection"](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+subcategory).

However, in [this paper by Adamek & Rosicky](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/30/41/30-41.pdf) the left adjoint is only called a "reflector", while the word "reflection" is reserved for components of the unit of adjunction.

I have two questions:

1. Are "reflections" and "reflectors" usually synonyms in the literature, or is there some variety in terminology?
2. In the [paper linked above](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/30/41/30-41.pdf), on top of p. 1308, where the authors describe the component of the unit of the reflective adjunction, shouldn't this be
   $$r_L:L\to EFL$$
   rather than
   $$r_L:L\to FL$$? One of the adjoint functors appears to be missing on the right-hand side.

Comment: For your second question, you are right $E$ should be included, but since $E$ is the inclusion of a subcategory the authors are suppressing the $E$ functor in the notation since $FL$ is literally an object of the larger category. For example, an Abelian group is a group, and the inclusion of the category of Abelian groups into the category of groups doesn't actually *do* anything. That said, I dislike these "implicit conversions" especially in a categorical context where a lot of interesting things are adjoints to "trivial" seeming functors including reflectors.